# Asp.net mvc4 config a route to achieve several urls

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

in my Controller：

```
public ActionResult Question(string id, int status = 1, int? page = 1, int? pageSize = 20) { //... }
```

RouteConfig：

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Route_UserQuestion",
    url: "User/{action}/{id}/{status}/{page}/{pagesize}.html",
    defaults: new { controller = "User", action = "Question", status = UrlParameter.Optional, page = UrlParameter.Optional, pagesize = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

but this is wrong，i want a config to implement several urls：

```
/User/Question/1234.html
/User/Question/1234/2.html
/User/Question/1234/2/1.html
/User/Question/1234/2/1/20.html
```

thanks!